# Creating a CBLReplication on a CBLDatabase using CouchBase Lite for iOS

Tags: ios, couchbase

I am following the guide [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-ios/#working-with-data-model-objects), the iOS Couchbase guide.  I am having trouble defining a pull replication.  I setup a database like this:

```
 self.masterData = [self.manager databaseNamed:@"masterData" error:&error];
if (!self.masterData) {

    NSString *masterdataerrormessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to create or connect to   
master data database with error: %@", error.localizedDescription];

    UIAlertView *masterDataDBAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Unable 
to create or connect to local master data database", nil) 
message:NSLocalizedString(masterdataerrormessage, nil) delegate:self  
cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


    [masterDataDBAlert show];
    return NO;

    }
```

I have a CBLReplication property called pullMasterData.  But when I TRY to do this:

```
self.pullMasterData = [self.masterData replicationFromURL:URL];
```

the selector **replicationFromURL** is not available on the self.masterData CBLdatabase object?  I must be doing something wrong here but not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  I checked the CBLDatabase.h file in the Headers folder of the Couchbase Lite framework.  The method to create a pull replication on the CBLDatabase object is **createPullReplication**, NOT replicationFromURL as noted in the iOS guide.  I should of checked the headers first :-)